# How to stop installing 2 instaces of same installer

Tags: install4j

I have created installer "Sample Product".
During first installation attempt installation was successful and install location was "c://Program files//Sample Product".

In windows installed program list, one entry has been added named "Sample Product".

During re-installation, I have selected different installation path (D://Sample Product).
Installation is successful.

However when I checked windows installed program list, one mo""re duplicate entry has been added  "Sample Product".

How can i stop creating two instances in windows installed program list.

If I repeat the installations with different location, it keeps on adding one more instance in windows Programs list.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the previous installation when you run the installer.

To find the previous installation directory, add a "Set a variable" action to the "Startup" node of the installer with the variable name "previousInstallationDir" following script:

```
ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo[] applicationInfos =
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById(context.getApplicationId());

if (applicationInfos.length > 1) {
    return applicationInfos[0].getInstallationDirectory().getPath();
} else {
    return "";
}
```

Then, add an "Uninstall previous installation" action to the "Installation" screen with the "Installation directory" property set to

```
${installer:previousInstallationDir}
```

Comment: I followed the steps suggested.                                                                                                     I have created installer "Sample Product". During first installation attempt installation was successful and install location was "c://Program files//Sample Product".
In windows installed program list, one entry has been added named "Sample Product"

Comment: During re-installation, I have selected different installation path(D://Sample Product). Installation is successful.

However when I checked windows installed program list, one more duplicate entry has been added "Sample Product".

Comment: You can look in the the .install4j/installation.log file to analyze what the actions are doing.

Comment: getting com.install4j.api.beans.UndefinedVariableException: installer:previousInstallationDir

Comment: I fixed the code snippet in the answer to define the variable with an empty string if no previous installation was found.

Comment: Still not working. added screenshots in question section.

Comment: So what is the variable value, still null?

Comment: Variable changed: previousInstallationDir=[class java.lang.String]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105152/discussion-between-chinmaya-and-ingo-kegel).

Comment: Steps are not working . I have added the log file in previous comment.

Comment: The log file file output say that the variable previousInstallationDir is now defined. The UndefinedVariableException should not happen anymore.

Comment: Yes Exception is showing. But on selecting dif installation dir, two instances are created in Windows Programs and Features list.

Comment: In principle this should work. I don't have enough information to analyze what is wrong in your setup. Generally speaking, install4j is a development environment and you have to put in some effort to debug things when they are not working. If the variable exception is still showing then try printing the variable i a "Run script" action just before the "Uninstall previous installation" action.